# Package inputenc Error Unicode \u8 not set up for use with Latex only on OSX

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm running my CV, which is compiled by calling pdflatex then biber then pdflatex twice. I have a .bib file generated in Mendeley which biber is reading.

When I run this script on my Mac laptop, I get the Unicode \u8 not set for use with Latex error that has been referenced in many questions on this site. However, when I run the same exact code on my Linux Mint machine, I don't get any errors and everything compiles cleanly.

I hypothesize that it might have something to do with the version of biber that I am using (1.8 on my Linux machine, 2.1 on the Mac) but am at a bit of a loss on this one.

Please note: original version contained an additional question regarding the numbering, but I will move that to a new question. I made the edit so that someone browsing this question in the future is not confused.

MWE as follows (only works as two separate files):

MyPapers.bib

```
@unpublished{exampletwo,
author = {Last-name, Firstname and lname, En\'{e}as},
booktitle = {In Review},
title = {{Pick a Title}}
}
@inproceedings{exampleone,
author = {Jones, Jim and Example, Jos\'{e}},
booktitle = {Sustentabilidade H{\'{\i}}drica}},
year = {2014}
}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,roman]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% character

\usepackage{csquotes}


%---------------------Bibliography and BiBLaTeX--------------------
% Use BibLaTeX
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}

\makeatletter

% Print labelnumber as actual number, plus item total, minus one
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{bbx@itemtotal}+1-#1\relax}

% Initialize category counters
\def\bbx@initcategory#1{\csnumgdef{bbx@count@#1}{0}}
\forlistloop{\bbx@initcategory}{\blx@categories}

% Increment category counters
\def\bbx@countcategory#1{%
  \ifentrytype{#1}
    {\csnumgdef{bbx@count@#1}{\csuse{bbx@count@#1}+1}%
     \addtocategory{#1}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \listbreak}
    {}}
\AtDataInput{\forlistloop{\bbx@countcategory}{\blx@categories}}

% Modify \bibbycategory to set item total
\patchcmd{\blx@bibcategory}
  {\blx@key@heading{#1}}
  {\blx@key@heading{#1}%
   \csnumdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}%
   \csnumgdef{bbx@itemtotal}{\csuse{bbx@count@#1}}}
  {}{}

\makeatother
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{unpublished}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{inproceedings}


\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{Publications and  Presentations}}
\defbibheading{unpublished}{\subsection*{Articles In Review}}
\defbibheading{inproceedings}{\subsection*{Conference Papers}}

\addbibresource{MyPapers.bib}

%------------------------ personal data -------------------------------------
\name{Firstname}{Name}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

% Publications
\nocite{*} % count all pubs as cited
\printbibheading
\bibbycategory

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are at a loss despite having the code which produces the problems, has it occurred to you that we may be at rather more of a loss without it? Try to produce a minimal example document which, when compiled, gives the errors mentioned on the Mac and not on the Mint. Then post that code so we can compile and reproduce the issue. (Most of us have got the 2.1 version so we should be able to do that.) You will, obviously, need to give us some `.bib` entries.  See [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).

Comment: It is better to post your code here. Otherwise, your question becomes useless when the link changes. Moreover, although some people will do so, others of us will not download zips from unknown sources for security reasons. As I say, some people will. But more people will read the code if you post it here.

Comment: didn't consider security, appreciate constructive criticism

Comment: In addition to the differences noted above, the Mac pdf has no accent above the letter i in the word "hidrica", whereas the Linux output has the accent. This problem is _not_ solved by chankging `\'{i}` to `\{\'{i}}`.

Comment: Try using the unicode character directly, especially if this is in your `.bib` file. I find that I have problems if I use the macro versions, but all is well if I use the characters themselves e.g. `\^a` will give me errors but `â` will work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the processing and sorting biber converts a number commands for accented chars to "glyph + combining accent", in you case "i + COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT (U+0300)".

pdflatex can't handle such "combining accents" and so you get an utf8-inputenc error. Unlike most other inputenc errors you can't correct it, you could only suppress the accent completly.

xelatex and lualatex can't handle them if the font hasn't the accent.

You can avoid the problem -- as cfr already wrote -- by using the correct glyph (`Hídrica`) in the input in the bib.

You can also avoid it by using `biber --output-safechars`. biber will then try to write such chars as macros to the bbl. You can also write your own recodedata and load it with `biber --recodedata=myrecode.xml`. With such a file you have full control about the output.

Comment: (+1) Good to have some explanation but why is it OK with the `e`? Why does it (presumably) translate that differently?

Comment: @cfr: No idea but I asked: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/82.

Comment: strange but works

Comment: marking as closed per recommendation of @cfr and will ask question about numbering separately

Answer (score 2):

Using the unicode characters rather than LaTeX macros is more reliable in my experience. For example, the following compiles without error:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@unpublished{exampletwo,
author = {Last-name, Firstname and lname, En\'{e}as},
booktitle = {In Review},
title = {{Pick a Title}}
}
@inproceedings{exampleone,
author = {Jones, Jim and Example, Jos\'{e}},
booktitle = {Sustentabilidade Hídrica}},
year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,roman]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% character

\usepackage{csquotes}


%---------------------Bibliography and BiBLaTeX--------------------
% Use BibLaTeX
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}

\makeatletter

% Print labelnumber as actual number, plus item total, minus one
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
  \number\numexpr\csuse{bbx@itemtotal}+1-#1\relax}

% Initialize category counters
\def\bbx@initcategory#1{\csnumgdef{bbx@count@#1}{0}}
\forlistloop{\bbx@initcategory}{\blx@categories}

% Increment category counters
\def\bbx@countcategory#1{%
  \ifentrytype{#1}
    {\csnumgdef{bbx@count@#1}{\csuse{bbx@count@#1}+1}%
     \addtocategory{#1}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \listbreak}
    {}}
\AtDataInput{\forlistloop{\bbx@countcategory}{\blx@categories}}

% Modify \bibbycategory to set item total
\patchcmd{\blx@bibcategory}
  {\blx@key@heading{#1}}
  {\blx@key@heading{#1}%
   \csnumdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{0}%
   \csnumgdef{bbx@itemtotal}{\csuse{bbx@count@#1}}}
  {}{}

\makeatother
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{unpublished}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{inproceedings}


\defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{Publications and  Presentations}}
\defbibheading{unpublished}{\subsection*{Articles In Review}}
\defbibheading{inproceedings}{\subsection*{Conference Papers}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%------------------------ personal data -------------------------------------
\name{Firstname}{Name}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

% Publications
\nocite{*} % count all pubs as cited
\printbibheading
\bibbycategory

\end{document}
```

and produces the expected output:

[image: output]

Don't ask me why it is fine with the `e` and not the `i`. I have no idea ;).

Comment: any thoughts on the numbering? when it's working correctly they are both [1], but when I run it on the mac it appears like you have it.

Comment: @mbarete I think that should be a new question as it concerns a rather different issue and somebody will likely be able to answer it fairly easily but that somebody is not, unfortunately, me :(. I assume that something about the internals of Biblatex you are using has changed but my knowledge of Biblatex is rather limited. (A sure sign of this is the number of questions I've asked about it on this site!)